# Constrained Quasi-Random Design Methodology

Tags: experiment-design, quasi-monte-carlo

I have a question about a practical design of experiment challenge I'm currently facing for my Ph.D., specifically about the selection of design points to investigate. The severely restricted case I'm running into isn't really covered by any books on the subject, however it would seem rather weird if there is no methodology for this yet. And I'm not quite ready to just wing it like many people suggest. So my question can be summarised as follows: Is there a way to determine optimally spread quasi random design points in a design space constrained by a series of curves with known boundaries?

Due to equipment time constraints two experiments can be run, and the design space in total has about 20 possible parameters to sweep. Of these twenty through careful conceptual design I managed to eliminate or control most of them. This results in three main parameters to be swept: $\alpha$, $R$, and $s$. Due to the need for expensive tooling to vary $s$ only three discrete points can be considered. These have been set to represent realistic values for real world conditions, and are currently in production.

Due to physical constraints not all combinations of $\alpha$, $R$, and $s$ are feasible, these design points are along a series of quite complex curves. After a considerable effort I managed to fit explicit functions to these resulting in a set of equations $R_i = f_i(\alpha)$ where $i = 1, 2, ..., 157$. The function contains gems like $(f(\alpha))^\alpha$, but is continuous and the differential exists throughout the design space. The functions are of the same form, with varying coefficients. However a further constraint not shown on this image is that a certain region is not applicable for each of the individual $s$ values.

While I could post the functions and full dataset I believe the following image explains the situation more clearly (*and I'd find it more satisfying to solve it myself :)* ). This shows the functions $R_i$ without removal of the regions which limit it due to $s$.:
[image: Design Space Curves $R$ and $\alpha$]

*(x-axis: $\alpha$ - y-axis: $R$)*

The dots on the image are from an earlier attempt at solving the problem based on $\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{(f(x) - f_{desired})^2 + (x - x_{desired})^2} = 0$ in combination with a Sobol sequence and shifting each point to the nearest point on a curve. The trick was then to generate enough points sequentially until I had the number of desired points in the real design space.  This does create a solution, but overall it would seem to have non-desirable spreading properties.

Due to the complexity of the equation I do not directly see a method to incorporate these equations into the quasi-random approach directly. So I was contemplating to try an approach where I generate a quasi random point to achieve optimal coverage of the design space, shift it using the above method to the nearest point on the nearest curve and take this into account to generate the next design point. This seems a bit simplistic, and probably wouldn't stand up very well to statistical scrutiny. So I was curious, is there a better method to approach this that I do not know about?